# リツイート機能に関してのコードの質問

Tags: ruby-on-rails

今ツイッターのようなWEBサイトを作っています。
他人のGithubを参照しているのですが”リツイート”する事に機能するviewファイルの_retweet.html.erb
に理解できないコードが出てきました。

```
<span id="retweet-<%= retweet.id %>">　の部分です。
```

"retweet-<%= retweet.id %>"の所が特にわからなく、
なぜ-記号が出できて、引数ではない形で<%= retweet.id %>を使用しているのかわかりません。
このコードの意味はなんなのでしょうか？
_retweet.html.erbの全体は

```
<div id="retweet-<%= retweet.id %>" class="micropost">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="avatar-content">
      <%= link_to retweet.source_tweet.user do %>
        <%= render 'partials/avatar', user: retweet.source_tweet.user, klass: 'avatar' %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <div class="post-content">
      <span class="name"><%= retweet.source_tweet.user.name %></span>
      <span class="username">@<%= retweet.source_tweet.user.username %></span>
      <div class="post">
        <%= retweet.source_tweet.tweet_text %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-content">
      <span><%= relative_time(retweet.source_tweet.created_at) %></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <div class="actions-content">
      <%= link_to reply_tweet_path(retweet.id), method: :post, remote: true do %>
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
      <% end %>
      <span id="retweet-<%= retweet.id %>">
        <%= render 'retweets/retweet_button', tweet_id: retweet.source_tweet.id %>
      </span>
      <span id="favor-tweet-<%= retweet.id %>">
        <%= render 'favorites/favorite_button', tweet_id: retweet.id %>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

のようになっています。

ちなみにretweets_controller.rbは

```
class RetweetsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def create
    @retweet = Retweet.new(source_tweet_id: params[:tweet_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @retweet = Retweet.new(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

のようになっています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ERB では**HTMLなどの文脈に関係なく**、書かれた位置にそのまま挿入されます。
記載された例だと、`<span id="retweet-1234">` のような出力になります。(`1234` は `retweet.id` の値。)

Answer (score 1):

erbでは`<% xxxx %>`で囲むことでrubyのコードとして解釈されます。
さらに`<%= xxxx %>`とすることでxxxxの戻り値が埋め込まれます。

よって`<span id="retweet-<%= retweet.id %>">`は
例としてretweet.idが100の場合、
`<span id="retweet-100">`と置き換えられて出力されます。